# Is it possible to get the address of the last hop of an unsuccessful tcp net.Dial?

Tags: go, tcp

My goal would be to decide whether an unsuccessful TCP connection made with net.Dial (it does not have to be net.Dial) failed due to a firewall/connectivity issue or just failure in the listener.

So essentially I would like to see something similar what I would with tcptraceroute.

1. timeout (what was the last ip)
2. open/closed port on dst

Also it would be nice to figure out which network interface (local address) was used for an unsuccessful connection

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", hostName + ":" + portNum)

if err != nil {
// is it possible to have socket values here
// maybe the last succesful hop before the connection failed?
}

// on succesfull conn it is straightforward
conn.LocalAddr()
conn.RemoteAddr()
```

Comment: If error occurs you can call traceroute utility to get hops information (like this one https://github.com/aeden/tracerout)